# PyDev and Django: PyDev breaking Django shell?

Tags: python, django, pydev

I've set up a new project, and populated it with simple models. (Essentially I'm following the [tut](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01).)

When I run `python manage.py shell` on the command line, it works fine:

```
>python manage.py shell

Python 2.6.4 (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 08:23:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from mysite.myapp.models import School
>>> School.objects.all()
[]
```

Works great. Then, I try to do the same thing in Eclipse (using a Django project that is composed of the same files.)

> Right click on mysite project >>
>   Django >> Shell with Django
>   environment

This is the output from the PyDev Console:

```
>>> import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
C:\Python26\python.exe 2.6.4 (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 08:23:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>>> 
>>> from django.core import management;import mysite.settings as settings;management.setup_environ(settings)
'path\\to\\mysite'
>>> from mysite.myapp.models import School
>>> School.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 68, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 83, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(list(self._iter))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 238, in iterator
    for row in self.query.results_iter():
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 287, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 2368, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 81, in cursor
    cursor = self._cursor()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 170, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the path to your database file, and the `DATABASE_NAME` setting in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is about not being open the database file. So I'd guess that the path to the database in your settings.py is a relative path, and PyDev starts the shell with a different current directory than you normally use.

If this is the case, change the `DATABASE_NAME` setting to an absolute path and it should work.

Comment: That was correct. Also, PyDev is giving me unresolved import errors for Django modules. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Rosarch: The output you posted shows Django being imported successfully, so I don't know why you'd get errors importing Django modules.

Comment: @Rosarch, I had the unresolved problem before, too. You need to enable "auto build" in PyDev preferences if I remember it correctly. For other system modules, it was already done when you created your interpreter first time. Without "auto build", you need to re-apply (basically rescan the python path) in the interpreter settings.

Comment: Use os.getcwd() I find the current directory is changed to HOME. Thanks!