# pydev directory django shell

Tags: pydev

I'm using PyDev in a django project of mine.
When I start the django sheel, the os.getcwd() command returns my home folder.
This is bad, since my code points to some resources by relative paths, assuming as current directory the directory containing the manage.py.

In this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746342/pydev-and-django-pydev-breaking-django-shell) someone recommended to use absolute paths to avoid this problem.
But I think it is a very bad practice, since things will not work when other people checkout the code into their computers.

The closest hint I found here:
http://old.nabble.com/-pydev---Users--how-to-set-working-directory-for-console--td25328455.html
It seems we can use "Run/Debug Settings" to set the current directory associated to a "runnable module". However, in this way we cannot associate the setting to the django console. I have tried to associate it with the manage.py, but it did not work.

So, the question: how to define the working directory of django shell?

Thank you,
Leonardo

Comment: Why not modify your PYTHONPATH with the location of your modules?

Comment: Hi, I believe adding the modules to the PYTHONPATH does not solve the problem of properly accessing resources (such as txt files, images, data bases etc).